# Element appears magically in PriorityQueue?

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue, a-star

**Code explanation:**
So I'm implementing the A* shortest-path algorithm for an ASCII map, with the passable fields being in an array (map[][]).
I have a PriorityQueue, and two HashMaps for Dijkstra-distance (d) and heuristic (h), that get initialised with pseudo-infinity and euclidian distance respectively.

The related while loop gets the element u of the priority queue, and then checks with its neighbors v if it can better their distance.

**My problem:**
In the marked lines, v is not found in d (for v=(171,434)), so I get a Null Pointer Exception, although for every element of the queue there is an initialised value in d and h. As you can see in the commented lines, I check if it (171,434) gets added into the priority queue, and it doesn't, but somehow it passes the if clause above. Any idea how it could sneak in?

```
Map<Point, Double> aStar(Point start, Point end){
    Map<Point, Double> d = new HashMap<Point, Double>();
    Map<Point, Double> h = new HashMap<Point, Double>();
    PriorityQueue<Point> queue = new PriorityQueue<Point>(fieldCount,new AStarComparator(d,h));
    for(int i=0;i<map.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<map[i].length;j++) {
            Point p = new Point(i,j);
            if(!p.equals(start) && map[i][j]) {
                d.put(p, Double.MAX_VALUE);
                h.put(p, p.distance(end));
                queue.add(p);
                //if(p.equals(new Point(171,434)))
                //  System.out.println("Added " + p + " with d = " + d.get(p));
            }
        }
    }
    d.put(start, 0.0);
    h.put(start, start.distance(end));
    queue.add(start);
    //System.out.println("Added " + start + " with d = " + d.get(start));

    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Polling " + queue.peek());
        Point u = queue.poll();
        Point v = new Point();
        for(int i= -1; i <= +1; i++) {
            for(int j= -1; j <= +1; j++) {
                v.x = u.x + i;
                v.y = u.y + j;

                if(queue.contains(v)){
-->                 System.out.println("u = " + u + ", v = " + v + ", d.get(v) = " + d.get(v) + ", d.contains(v) = " + d.containsKey(v));**
                    double weight = (i == 0 || j == 0) ? 1 : Math.sqrt(2);
-->                 if(d.get(u) + weight < d.get(v)) {
                        d.put(v, d.get(u) + weight);
                        //refresh queue
                        queue.remove(v);
                        queue.add(v);
                        System.out.println("Refreshing with " + v);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

**Edit:**

Stacktrace (with 117 being the line of the if clause):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at StarcraftShortestPath.aStar(StarcraftShortestPath.java:117)
at StarcraftShortestPath.findPath(StarcraftShortestPath.java:141)
at StarcraftTest.test1stRoute(StarcraftTest.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Stack trace please. The only way you can get an NPE in the `println()` call is if `d` is null.

Comment: Do you correctly override `hashcode` and `equals` in your point class?

Comment: @EJP I get the NPE in the if clause, and I assumed that's because of `d.get(v)` being null, what I noticed in the `print()`.

Comment: @EJP unwrapping the `Double` in the if-condition can cause the NullPointerException.

Comment: @Calculator It's the java.awt.Point class

Comment: What exactly is the point of `queue.remove(v)/queue.add(v)`? This either does nothing or exhibits a conceptual bug.

Comment: @EJP I pasted that from my lecture material, according to my prof it's a way to 'refresh' the queue to prevent bugs or something.

Comment: Removing and then adding the same thing accomplishes nothing. It's a bug. You should remove `v` before you update it, and add it afterwards. And there is a second bug: you must use a new `v` every time around the inner loop. If you use the same `v` you are updating it without telling the PQ, which will corrupt the PQ if it is ordered on those values.

Comment: where does the variable "map" come from?

Comment: @efekctive As I wrote in the explanation, it stores the information of where the passable fields of the map are (boolean).

Comment: I asked you for the stack trace 25 minutes ago. Where is it?

Comment: @EJP Edited it into the question, sorry, thought it was irrelevant because there was no exception in the `println` (as you thought).

Comment: Have you tried to place a break point to check why 171,434 is not added to the queue? Evaluate those conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and then adding the same thing accomplishes nothing. It's a bug. You should remove `v` before you update it, and add it afterwards.

And there is a second bug: you must use a new `v` every time around the inner loop. If you use the same `v` you are updating it without telling the PQ, which will corrupt the PQ if it is ordered on those values.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. That's what you get for trying to economize new object allocations.
However, reordering the queue operations didn't change anything as far as i can see, so I'm not sure if it's a 'bug', isn't it more like bad practice?

Comment: Either pointless or a nasty piece of practice, not sure which as I don't know the algorithm.